# null not appearing in the query...Try referencing the or starting the middle table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Topology db: Asset table -> Geometry table -> Valid_value table -> Unit_of_Measure

how can i start a query by referencing or starting from 
Valid_value table and joining the rest of the tables. My objective here is to show a data where valid_value_descr is not empty. the Original query was (see the query) but the problem was- I have to show the null values of the  dbo.GEOMETRY.GEOMETRIC_VALUE. If I used the query below it doesn't show the null values... I have to start from valid value table then connecting the rest. How can i do this..

```
SELECT dbo.ASSET.OID,
       dbo.ASSET.ASSET_ID,
       dbo.ASSET.ASSET_NAME,
       dbo.GEOMETRY.GEOMETRIC_VALUE,
       dbo.VALID_VALUE.VALID_VALUE_DESCR
FROM   dbo.ASSET
       INNER JOIN dbo.GEOMETRY
               ON dbo.ASSET.OID = dbo.GEOMETRY.ASSET_OID
       INNER JOIN dbo.VALID_VALUE
               ON dbo.GEOMETRY.GEOMETRIC_TYPE_OID = dbo.VALID_VALUE.OID
       INNER JOIN dbo.UNIT_OF_MEASURE
               ON dbo.VALID_VALUE.UNIT_OF_MEASURE_OID = dbo.UNIT_OF_MEASURE.OID
```

Comment: Use LEFT JOIN with GEOMETRY table to get NULL values in case of exact match not found.

Comment: I tried... is it possible to start a query as this topology db: Asset table <- Geometry table <- Valid_value table -> Unit_of_Measure

Comment: `NULL` values of what?  I can't follow the question:  "My objective here is to show a data where valid_value_descr is not empty. "  Then:  "I have to show the null values of the dbo.GEOMETRY.GEOMETRIC_VALUE".

Comment: Can you elaborate on the relationship between the tables a little more?  (Also, please clarify what you're looking for with respect to Gordon's comment.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have read your problem right, you have more values in your VALID_VALUE table than will match up to values in your ASSET or GEOMETRY tables, which means that if you want to start from ASSET, go through GEOMETRY, and still see all values in VALID_VALUE, you need to use a `RIGHT JOIN` to get to the table that you want to see all the rows of:

```
SELECT dbo.ASSET.OID,
       dbo.ASSET.ASSET_ID,
       dbo.ASSET.ASSET_NAME,
       dbo.GEOMETRY.GEOMETRIC_VALUE,
       dbo.VALID_VALUE.VALID_VALUE_DESCR
FROM   dbo.ASSET
       RIGHT JOIN dbo.GEOMETRY
               ON dbo.ASSET.OID = dbo.GEOMETRY.ASSET_OID
       RIGHT JOIN dbo.VALID_VALUE
               ON dbo.GEOMETRY.GEOMETRIC_TYPE_OID = dbo.VALID_VALUE.OID
       LEFT JOIN dbo.UNIT_OF_MEASURE
               ON dbo.VALID_VALUE.UNIT_OF_MEASURE_OID = dbo.UNIT_OF_MEASURE.OID
```

(*The final `LEFT JOIN` may need to be changed back to an `INNER JOIN`, as it appears that the purpose of that join is to restrict results since none of its columns are in the result set.*)

This query will give you all of the rows in VALID_VALUE, with everything else joined onto it as though you had started there and `LEFT JOIN`ed everything on.

Comment: @Jake see my updated answser, hopefully it is closer to what you need.  If not, maybe you could provide some sample data and expected results